# Eigenvalue inequality $v^tAv \geq \lambda \|v\|_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say you have a vector $v$ and a matrix $A$ whose minimum eigenvalue is $\lambda$. I have seen people use the following inequality, but I don't understand how they arrived at it.

$$v^t A v \geq \lambda \|v\|_2$$

Could someone explain to me why this holds?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient#Bounds_for_Hermitian_M

Comment: I think you need the square of the norm on the right side of that inequality. E.g., if $A$ is the identity matrix, then the left side is $v^tv=\|v\|^2$.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments and the answer, ben?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the simplified case when $A$ has a complete set of eigenvectors that form a basis for your vector space.

Take $v_1$ to be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. Then, you should check that $v_1^T Av_1=v_1^T \lambda v_1=\lambda||v_1||^2$ so the minimum can be attained.

Now for a different eigenvector $v_i$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i\geq \lambda_1$, observe that $v_i^T A v_i=\lambda_i ||v_i||^2$.

If we normalize our eigenvectors to have norm $1$, then we can write any vector as a linear combination of the eigenvectors.

i.e. $w=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$

I think you probably want to say that $A$ is symmetric. Then, $v_i^T A v_j=0$ whenever $v_i\neq v_j$. (Use that $v_i^T A v_j=\lambda_j v_i^T v_j$ and do the same thing for $v_j^T A v_i$ to deduce this).

$w^T A w=\sum |a_i|^2 \lambda_i ||v_i||^2=\sum |a_i|^2 \lambda_i\geq \lambda_1(\sum |a_i|^2)=\lambda_1 ||v||_2^2 $ where we used the orthogonality of $v_i$ with respect to the inner product induced by the symmetric matrix $A$.